# How do I embed a 2nd level menu block?

Tags: 8

I need to embed the 2nd level menu that show up in my 2nd level page /maintenance

in the next level page /maintenance/add-task

Drupal does not have this kind of setting, I'm looking a lot in the core files to try to figure out the proper API code to embed, one of my attempts:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('block_modules_menu_second_level');
$variables['menu_second_level'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);
```

That code is for a simple block, or a custom block.
How to evoke the drupal core menu level 2?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure, whether I got you right. Here's my guess:
Depending on which theme you use, it may be that it is not a problem with the menu template. In my case, the (main) menu was configured to show only one level in the block settings.

I found out by chance, here is how to change it:

1. Go to https://<yourdrupalpage>/admin/structure/block
2. on the respective menu block item (e.g. main menu) click *configure*
3. adjust the number of visible menu levels to your needs

that should to the trick

Comment: You just saved me a few hours of searching. You rock!